# Insert rows into a table with a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-view

I have created a table name `viewex`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE viewex (
  sno INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  email VARCHAR(30),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  contact VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Inserted data to the table.

Now I am intrested to insert data only for 3 columns (name, address, contact):

```sql
INSERT INTO viewex (name, address, contact)
VALUES ('celcabs', 'good', 'bad');
```

Now the issue is..........
Is it possible to create the view for the query

```sql
INSERT INTO viewex (name, address, contact)
VALUES ('celcabs', 'good', 'bad');
```

Answer (score 13):

As of PostgreSQL 9.3 you can insert into and update "simple views": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: And for "complex views" you can create an instead of insert/update/delete trigger.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is an `updatable view` and postgresql doesn't have direct support for them.

You can get the effect using [CREATE RULE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createrule.html) - that page has info on how to get the effect of an updatable view.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert rows into a table with a view.

For example, you create `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  first_name VARCHAR(20),
  last_name VARCHAR(20),
  age INTEGER
);
```

Then, you insert 2 rows into `person` table as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', 27), (2, 'David', 'Miller', 32);
```

Then, calling `person` gets the result as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | first_name | last_name | age
----+------------+-----------+-----
  1 | John       | Smith     |  27
  2 | David      | Miller    |  32
(2 rows)
```

Then, you create `my_v` view as shown below:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_v AS
  SELECT first_name, age FROM person;
```

Now, you can insert 2 rows to `person` table with `my_v` as shown below. *`id` and `last_name` are not usable:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_v (first_name, age) 
VALUES ('Robert', 18), ('Mark', 40);
```

Then, 2 rows are inserted to `person` table as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | first_name | last_name | age
----+------------+-----------+-----
  1 | John       | Smith     |  27
  2 | David      | Miller    |  32
    | Robert     |           |  18
    | Mark       |           |  40
(4 rows)
```